# How to calculate values from functions without returning them or setting them global (for numba.cuda)?

Tags: python, function, cuda, return, numba

I am trying to run this simple code on a CUDA GPU. The module I am using for this is `numba.cuda`:

```
import numba
from numba import cuda

@numba.cuda.jit
def function_4(j, k):
    l = j + k
    return l

l = function_4(1, 2)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    l = function_4(1, 2)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 758, in __call__
    kernel = self.specialize(*args)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 769, in specialize
    kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 785, in compile
    **self.targetoptions)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 57, in compile_kernel
    cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, types.void, args, debug=debug, inline=inline)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 46, in compile_cuda
    locals={})
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 568, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 339, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 401, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 381, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 372, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 332, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 291, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 264, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 98, in run_pass
    raise_errors=self._raise_errors)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 70, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate(raise_errors=raise_errors)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 986, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No conversion from int64 to none for '$12return_value.4', defined at None

File "test2.py", line 7:
def function_4(j, k):
    <source elided>
    l = j + k
    return l
    ^

[1] During: typing of assignment at /home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (7)

File "test2.py", line 7:
def function_4(j, k):
    <source elided>
    l = j + k
    return l
    ^
```

`numba.cuda` does not support the `return` statement. So how do I use functions to calculate values? The `global` statement seems not to be supported either:

```
import numba
from numba import cuda

@numba.cuda.jit
def function_4(j, k):
    global l
    l = j + k

function_4(1, 2)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amu/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    function_4(1, 2)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 758, in __call__
    kernel = self.specialize(*args)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 769, in specialize
    kernel = self.compile(argtypes)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 785, in compile
    **self.targetoptions)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 57, in compile_kernel
    cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, types.void, args, debug=debug, inline=inline)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 46, in compile_cuda
    locals={})
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 568, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 339, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 401, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 381, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 372, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 332, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 291, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 264, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/untyped_passes.py", line 86, in run_pass
    func_ir = interp.interpret(bc)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/interpreter.py", line 116, in interpret
    flow.run()
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/byteflow.py", line 107, in run
    runner.dispatch(state)
  File "/home/amu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/byteflow.py", line 269, in dispatch
    raise UnsupportedError(msg, loc=self.get_debug_loc(inst.lineno))
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
Use of unsupported opcode (STORE_GLOBAL) found

File "test.py", line 7:
def function_4(j, k):
    <source elided>
    global l
    l = j + k
    ^
```

Comment: can't you just write `return j+k` i your function ?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13/CUDAJit.html), you must pass an output array to which to write. Note that ``numba.cuda`` is intended for writing kernels: the function should not do the entire computation, it should only compute the element of its current thread.

Comment: @Mr_Spaar the `return` statement itself is not supported by `numba.cuda`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Do I understand it correctly that I have to create an `array` outside the `function`, then calculate values and fill the `array` inside the function, which will change the `array` gobally?

Comment: Are you aware how kernel and GPU programming works in principle? You pass arrays to the GPUs, and the kernel function is applied to each position in the arrays. The arrays are changed inplace, which might seem "global" if you have a global reference to them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I haven't worked with it yet. I have read [Writing Cuda Kernels](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/kernels.html)

Comment: It might be worth updating the question with an example for which CUDA is actually applicable. Adding two integers is not useful for CUDA.

Comment: All arguments need to be passed as arrays. And kernels require launch configuration arguments. This is explicitly discussed in the documentation

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Your code would need to look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import numba 
from numba import cuda 

@cuda.jit 
def function_4(i, j, k):
     i[0] = j[0] + k[0]

j = np.array([1],  dtype=np.int32)
k = np.array([2],  dtype=np.int32)
i = np.zeros_like(j)

function_4[1,1](i, j, k)
print(i[0])
```

[Note code written on a phone in an airport departure lounge, never tested, use at own risk]

Basically everything had to be passed as arrays with explicit dtypes. If your intention is to write kernels, you would be better served starting in CUDAs native C++ dialect, which is well documented, and then coming back to Numba, which isn't. Then everything will be self-evident

Comment: Writing code in a sans serif font while  fighting autocorrect on a phone isn't as easy as it looks

Comment: You make it look easy.